# Populate a dropdown button with options from a variable passed to class as provider argument

Tags: flutter

I have a class called Category, and each Category has a list of Subcategory objects. Both category and subcategory classes have title fields.

So...

- category1

  - subcategory1
  - subcategory2
- category2

  - subcategory3
- category3
- category4

  - subcategory4
  - subcategory5
  - subcategory6

I have a list view of Category objects, clicking one navigates to a form screen where the user enters some data and saves a SavedItem object. One field they need to complete is to choose the subcategory from a dropdown button. If they tapped category4 then the options are subcategory4, subcategory5 and subcategory6.

I get the category object as a provider argument and the subcategories via `List<Subcategory> subCategories = providedCategory.subcategories.toList();`

How do I go from there to a working dropdown? I am new to Flutter so this is bending my head... the below threw an error which I searched and it says the dropdown options aren't unique but the contents of the subcategory list of objects are each unique.

```
There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: . 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
```

```
DropdownButton(
  value: selectval,
  onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
      selectval = value.toString();
    });
  },
  items: subCategories.map((item) {
    return DropdownMenuItem(
      value: item, child: Text(item.title));
  }).toList(),
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you like to using String dataType on dropDown menu, it will be

And `String? selectval;`

```dart
DropdownButton<String?>(
  value: selectval,
  onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
      selectval = value;
    });
  },
  items: subCategories.map((item) {
    return DropdownMenuItem<String?>(
      value: item.title, child: Text(item.title));
  }).toList(),
),
```

Or for the item you like, don't use `.toString()` on item case.